# Gradle: task to run some class

Tags: java, gradle

I have a gradle project.
I want to run some generator with it's own main, that should be in project and with it's own dependencies.
e.g.

```
project root

    |
    |-src/main/java
    |-src/main/kotlin <----here's my project's main class
```

I want to:

```
project root
    |
    |-src/main/java
    |-src/main/kotlin <----here's my project's main
    |-mylibs/generators/foogenerator <- has it's own main, want to run it from gradle with it's own dependencies
```

Comment: Consider looking at the `application` plugin for Gradle - it's one of the built-in plugins you can find in their user guide.

Comment: Have you thought about creating separate module for `foogenerator`?